# Calculate Euler's totient function for perfect squares

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

Can $φ(n)$ be easily calculated when $n$ is a perfect square i.e. there exists a natural number $k$ so that $n=k^2$?

Comment: $\varphi(n)$ can be easily calculated when you know the prime factorisation of $n$.

Comment: And if $n=p^2*q^2$ where $p$ and $q$ are two large prime numbers, can $φ(n)$ be easily calculated?

Comment: If you know $p$ and $q$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Well, technically knowing one is enough as it implies the other :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p_1$ through $p_n$ form the unique primes in the prime factorization of $k$ (so not including multiplicities) we can use the following definition:

$$\varphi(k) = k\left(1 - \frac1{p_1}\right)\left(1 - \frac1{p_2}\right)\cdots\left(1 - \frac1{p_n}\right)$$

And the knowledge that each prime in the factorization of $k$ occurs twice in $k^2$, without introducing any new primes to find out:

$$\varphi(k^2) = k^2\left(1 - \frac1{p_1}\right)\left(1 - \frac1{p_2}\right)\cdots\left(1 - \frac1{p_n}\right)$$

$$\varphi(k^2) = k\varphi(k)$$

Comment: So if $φ(n)$ is hard to calculate so that is $φ(n^2)$?

Comment: @MPlesa Correct.