# Showing $\phi(n^2) = n\, \phi(n)$

Tags: totient-function

How can I show this for Euler's $\phi$ function?
$$\phi(n^2) = n\,\phi(n)$$

Ive been struggling a lot with this problem, I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Try an example, such as $n=6$.  Can you list the coprime numbers for $6$ and $36$ and then spot the pattern?

Comment: Can you show $\text{hcf}(n,k)=1 \iff \text{hcf}(n^2,k)=1$? [$\text{gcd}$ if you prefer that notation]

Comment: [Euler's product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler's_product_formula) implies that $\frac{\phi(n^2)}{n^2} = \frac{\phi(n)}{n}$ because $n^2$ and $n$ have exactly the same prime factors.

Comment: Hint: First remember, for prime $p$, $\phi (p^k)=(p-1)(p^{k-1})$. Prove the property for prime powers, and then recall the fact that $\phi$ is a multiplicative function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\begin{align}\frac{\varphi(n^2)}{n^2}&=\Pi_{p|n^2} (1-\frac{1}{p})\\&=\Pi_{p|n} (1-\frac{1}{p}) \\&=\frac{\varphi(n) }{n}\end{align} $

Note : $p|n^2=n\cdot n$ implies $p|n$  . Hence $p|n^2$ iff $p|n$

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912792/calculate-eulers-totient-function-for-perfect-squares?noredirect=1).

Answer (score 0):

Remember, $\phi(n)$ counts the integers $1\le k\le n$ coprime to $n$.

Consider $\phi(n^2)$. For any $1\le k\le n^2$, we can divide $k$ by $n$ to write $k=nq+r$ (with $q$ the quotient $0\le q<n$ and $r$ the remainder $0\le r<n$). Note $k$ coprime to $n^2$ iff it's coprime to $n$, iff $k-qn=r$ is coprime to $n$. Thus, there are $n\phi(n)$ different $k$s we're counting, where $n$ is the number of options for $q$ and $\phi(n)$ is the number of options for $r$. Therefore, $\phi(n^2)=n\phi(n)$.